# base64 encoding/decoding in php

Tags: php

I have implemented a cookie mechanism in my site.
All cookies that i wanted to store are in a array with their TTL, value, name ...

When i want to set the cookie, i serialize the tab, then i gzcompress and finally i base64_encode

```
base64_encode(gzcompress(serialize($array)))
```

My problem is sometime, when i get the cookie with

```
$_COOKIE[name]
```

the base64_encoded string is all in lowercase characters.

So my question is : 
- is that possible that all characters are in lowercase format (base64_encoded)

Or maybe i'am doing something wrong but the problem does not appear all the time and i can't reproduce the bug.

Comment: Can you not use `strtolower` before parse the cookie?

Comment: does base64_decode not give you correctly compressed data?

Comment: Can you please show full code. How you prepare data and save and how restore

Comment: off topic, but how much data are you putting into the cookie? bear in mind that the entire contents of the cookies are transmitted in full in both directions for every request/response made between the browser and server. If you have a large cookie string and your site makes more than a few requests, this can have a noticeable performance impact. If this is the case, you might find `$_SESSION` a better place to store it (which would also handily eliminate the need to do all that serializing and encoding as well)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, a Base64-encoded string can be all lowercase.  The probability of this happening (for random input data, which compressed data pretty well approximates) is about (36 / 64)<sup>4 *N* / 3</sup>, where *N* is the length of the input in bytes, and 4 *N* / 3 is thus the approximate length of the output (excluding padding).

As it happens, (36 / 64)<sup>4</sup> ≈ 0.100113 is very close to 1 / 10, and so, to a very good approximation, the probability that a random Base64 string contains no uppercase letters goes down by a factor of 10 for every four characters in length.

Thus, for example, a random 8-character Base64 string (corresponding to a random 6-byte input) has about a 1% chance of containing no uppercase letters, while the corresponding probability for a random 12-character Base64 string (corresponding to a random 9-byte input) is about 0.1%, and so on.